# AWS Custom AMI not running userdata script

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, cloud-init

We bake AMI's and lately I have wanted to run some user-data scripts to notify cloud formation when the instance is done booting and put it into service. I am using cfn-signal to do this. On the original ubuntu image the script will execute but after baking our custom AMI the user-data script is not run.

If I place "#cloud-boothook" at the top of the script it does execute but because it executes so early its not useful for notifying when the machine is up. I am hoping someone knows where the flag or file is that indicates to cloudinit that it is a first boot of a machine.

I also tried modifying the config as was suggested [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475374/how-do-i-make-cloud-init-startup-scripts-run-every-time-my-ec2-instance-boots)

I know there must be a flag or file I can remove before the AMI creation process but am unable to find any information on what the flag or file might be.

Answer (score 2):

As I tested, there were some bootstrap data in `/var/lib/cloud` directory.
After I cleared that directory, **User Data** script worked normally.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/cloud/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that cloud-init is not running during this time. Otherwise you need to delete it again.

This is especially true if you try to delete `/var/lib/cloud/` inside user-data. In this case you should use something like:

```
echo "rm -rf /var/lib/cloud/*" | at now + 1 min
```

at the end of user-data script.