# EC2 custom AMI in autoscaling group not running user data script

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/645281/aws-custom-ami-not-running-userdata-script/786034#786034),

My user data is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'test' > /home/ubuntu/user-script.txt
Using a standard Ubuntu AMI, this works fine.
```

I have a custom AMI that I have created by standing up a standard Ubuntu AMI, running an Ansible playbook and creating an AMI from that. When I configure my launch config to use my custom AMI, user data is NOT run. There is no other difference.

I understand that it may be due to the semaphore files so I stood up an instance of my AMI, deleted /var/lib/cloud/sem/* and created a new AMI. I created a new launch configuration with this AMI and got the same result.

I repeated this process, this time removing /var/lib/cloud/*. Same result.

Any ideas? This has got to be possible, right?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the cause of this.

My Ansible playbook was removing a package from Ubuntu called "unattended-upgrades" which presumably the Amazon utilities use.

Likewise, my second playbook was removing the ubuntu user. The Amazon utility may also use that.

When I disable these roles, the AMI works with user data as expected.